# Chatter Answers - Is it available for Salesforce Platform edition as well?

Tags: editions, chatter-answers

Chatter Answers - Is it available for Salesforce Platform edition

Comment: Do you perhaps mean Professional Edition? Its not clear to me what else you could mean by "Platform Edition".

Comment: http://www.salesforce.com/platform/overview/

Comment: http://www.salesforce.com/crm/editions-pricing-platform.jsp

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Chatter Answers is available in: Enterprise, Developer, Performance,
>   and Unlimited Editions.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=questions_portal_setup_about.htm&language=en_US

So no, it is not available. Among other reasons, it requires Cases.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Salesforce Communities - License Features](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/index_Left.htm#CSHID=dev_package_features_pe_ge.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/dev_package_features_pe_ge.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp), Communities aren't available at all for Group or Professional Editions. In [How to Select the Right Sales Cloud Edition](http://www.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf), According to page 2, Chatter Answers is available for Customer Communities, Customer Plus Communities, and Partner Communities; all of which are require an additional license. Finally, that document also indicates those Communities are only available for Enterprise and Unlimited Editions.

To be safe, check with your SF customer service rep to verify this as things seem to change frequently.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Platform edition is something different. Please do research before providing an answer. A Google search for "salesforce platform edition" gave me this: http://www.salesforce.com/crm/editions-pricing-platform.jsp

Comment: Odd, what I see on that page is pricing bundles built around either Force.com Enterprise Edition or Force.com PXE Edition. Linked from that page is [How to select tHe right 
PlatForm subscription](http://www2.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/misc/DS_Force_Pricing_Comparison.pdf) gives a more detailed comparison. If built around Enterprise Edition, it would appear that **the research I did** provided an accurate answer, but as we all know, SF is constantly evolving, thus the advice to check with a customer service rep. Go chastise someone else.

Comment: Cal, you're dangerous here because you answer questions, but you don't know what you don't know. I'm serious. I'm not chastising - I'm telling another user that his answers are sometimes low quality and demonstrate lack of knowledge. There are plenty of us who know what platform edition is. If you don't know something, don't answer it. Plain and simple.